# leaflet mapbox vector tile javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, mapbox

I am not familiar with nodejs environment, I want to get the js file of [Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile)

Is it possible to use it without installing nodejs?

Comment: Leaflet is a Javascript Library, unrelated to Node.js. Please try the examples given in the [readme file](https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile#readme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is download the file from GitHub. [Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile/master/dist/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile.js) is the link to the source javascript file, [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile/master/dist/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile.min.js) is the link to the minified file. The minified file is recommended, as it is smaller and takes less time for the browser to fetch.

Once you have downloaded the file, put it in the same directory as your html document, and then place the following code in the `head` section of your html document:

```html
<script src="Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile.min.js"></script>
```

If you searched a little bit, you could find answers for this, as all you have to do is download a file from GitHub. Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)